# how can fix the error in this code and how can change from for loop to recursion ? i'm beginner in programming :)

Tags: java

i try to make method that can be find the profit for some input and calculation.
but i think there a problem in a length of Array or somewhat i don't know.
also i wanna try it by using recursive but how to implement ?
please i need your helps ^_^
thanks

```
public class MatlabLAB2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int capital = 100;
        int nDay = 7;
        int[] buyP = {5, 20, 7, 10, 4, 80, 1};
        int[] sellP = {25, 50, 100, 3, 10, 2, 95};

        findProfit(capital, nDay, buyP, sellP);
    }

    public static void findProfit(int capital, int NDay, int[] BuyingP, int[] SellingP) {


        int[] Array = new int[NDay];
        int Profit = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i <= BuyingP.length; i++) {

            for (int j = i; j <= SellingP.length; j++) {

                for (int k = 0; k <= NDay-1; k++) {
                    Array[k] = (capital / BuyingP[i]) * SellingP[j];
                }
                Profit = findMaxOfArray(Array);

            }
        }
        System.out.println(Profit);
    }

    public static int findMaxOfArray(int[] a) {
        int max = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= a.length-1; i++) {
            if (a[i] >= max) {
                max = a[i];
            }
        }
        return max;
    }
}


the result:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7
at matlab.lab.pkg2.MatlabLAB2.findProfit(MatlabLAB2.java:24)
at matlab.lab.pkg2.MatlabLAB2.main(MatlabLAB2.java:11)
Java Result: 1
```

Comment: Please explain what u want to achieve with recursion. First you should research and  try if you get stuck then you can ask it.

Comment: I wanna do this code by recursion not by for loop in method findProfit how to do it ?

Answer (score 3):

You are iterating the loop till

```
(int i = 0; i <= BuyingP.length; i++)
```

it should be iterated till

```
(int i = 0; i < BuyingP.length; i++)
```

same with j loop

Comment: Please mark as accepted if it solves your problem. Comment if you need any further explanation

Answer (score 1):

You have two options to fix this.

1.

```
public static void findProfit(int capital, int NDay, int[] BuyingP, int[] SellingP) {
    int[] Array = new int[NDay];
    int Profit = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i <= BuyingP.length-1; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j <= SellingP.length-1; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k <= NDay-1; k++) {
                Array[k] = (capital / BuyingP[i]) * SellingP[j];
            }

            Profit = findMaxOfArray(Array);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Profit);
}
```

2.

```
public static void findProfit(int capital, int NDay, int[] BuyingP, int[] SellingP) {
    int[] Array = new int[NDay];
    int Profit = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < BuyingP.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j < SellingP.length; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k <= NDay-1; k++) {
                Array[k] = (capital / BuyingP[i]) * SellingP[j];
            }

            Profit = findMaxOfArray(Array);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Profit);
}
```

Because in your code your array goes from 0 to 6 and you are trying to take array[7] which is out of your array's bound.